# service does not listen to certain broadcasts

Tags: android, service

My service:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (debug_mode) {Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");}
        super.onCreate();
        // set receivers
        m_filter.addAction("PREPARE_AUDIO");
        m_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (debug_mode) {Log.i(TAG,"broadcast received: " + intent.getAction());}
                if (intent.getAction().equals("PREPARE_AUDIO")) {
                    set_up_audio();
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(m_receiver, m_filter);
    }
```

and my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      if (debug_mode) Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide);
      // start service
      startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
      if (debug_mode) {Log.i(TAG,"onStart");}
      super.onStart();
      // prepare audio
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction("PREPARE_AUDIO");
      sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

This won't trigger the `BroadcastReceiver` in my service. It won't trigger it either if I put the code on `onCreate` or `onResume`. It will trigger it, however, if put e.g. on some `Listener` associated with a `Button`, or in the activity's `onStop` callback. Why is that?

Comment: Presumably your service is not running yet by the time `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, or `onResume()` are being called.

Comment: and how I can make sure it's running? I edited my answer with the code that starts the service

Comment: The simpler solution is to not try to send the broadcast so soon. You should not need to do that. If you need the service to do something right away, have it do so in `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: that did it - you should put that on an answer to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to send a broadcast right away, just have the service do its setup work in its `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()` method.

Note that using system broadcasts for this is a fairly bad idea, unless your service is in a separate process from your UI. Even then, you need to think through the security, as any app can tell your service what to do, by sending it broadcasts.

If your service and UI will be in the same process, use an in-process event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus), not only for improved security, but for better performance.